# How can I modify problem for flex-flow on ie11?

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I want to arrange the element li horizontally, and when the length is exceeded, the next element is placed on the top line.

Parent Div-box have "position:fixed;" option.

Chrome,Edge is Ok. But IE11 is not.

If you have tip for this problem. Please tell me about.

```
                    ul {
                    list-style-type: none;
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;

                    li {
                        display: inline-block;
                        width: 200px;
                        height: 30px;
                        font-size: 20px;

                        span {
                            font-size: 28px;
                        }
                    }

            <ul>
                <li id="conErr1"><span>1</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
                <li id="conErr2"><span>2</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
                <li id="conErr3"><span>3</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
                <li id="conErr4"><span>4</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
                <li id="conErr5"><span>5</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
                <li id="conErr6"><span>6</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
                <li id="conErr7"><span>7</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
                <li id="conErr8"><span>8</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
                <li id="conErr9"><span>9</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
                <li id="conErr10"><span>10</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: I just tested this in Internet Explorer 11.134.17763.0, and it appears to behave the same as with Chrome. What are you expecting to happen, and what currently happens for you?

Comment: @Obsidian Age In ie11, Showing just 1 line. li elements is overflowed.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see that with your above code. Can you please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem? :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Oh, Parent div have 'position:fixed;bottom:0;left;0' option. I found cause but i don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that you could just add width attribute to parent div, and then it will work will on IE.
Here is my testing code.
CSS.

```
<style>
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    span {
        font-size: 28px;
    }

</style>
```

HTML.

```
 <div style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;width: 100%;">
    <ul>
        <li id="conErr1"><span>1</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
        <li id="conErr2"><span>2</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
        <li id="conErr3"><span>3</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
        <li id="conErr4"><span>4</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
        <li id="conErr5"><span>5</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
        <li id="conErr6"><span>6</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
        <li id="conErr7"><span>7</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
        <li id="conErr8"><span>8</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
        <li id="conErr9"><span>9</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
        <li id="conErr10"><span>10</span>번 수신기 통신장애</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: the running result]

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is really easy to understand.